# How to trigger a job when one job is finished

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jobs

I used this:

```
  post {
      always {
          sh "echo Jenkins Job is Done"
          junit 'target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
          echo 'Run darkWeb Test pipeline!'
          build job: 'DarkWeb'
      }
```

and it works. The problem is that the original job continuing running while the second job (DarkWeb) is running too.

I want the 'DarkWeb' job to run only **after the original job is completely finished**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following syntax:
`build job: 'Darkweb', wait: false`
The wait: false token would allow the first job to finish without waiting for the completion of second job.
Let me know if it works!